# ostream and ofstream operator overloading ambiguity problem

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, overloading

I'm trying to overload ofstream and ostream operators but I have a problem. I'm saving active game while using ofstream and printing on terminal by using ostream.

Here's the **error I get**:

```
hex_game.cpp: In member function ‘void Hex::saveGame(const string&)’:
hex_game.cpp:375:18: warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:
  375 |  myfile << (*this);
      |                  ^
hex_game.cpp:193:11: note: candidate 1: ‘std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream&, const Hex&)’
  193 | ofstream& operator <<(ofstream& fileOutput, const Hex& obj){
      |           ^~~~~~~~
hex_game.cpp:207:10: note: candidate 2: ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Hex&)’
  207 | ostream& operator <<(ostream& outputStream, Hex& obj){
```

**LINE 375:**

```
 void Hex::saveGame(const string& file_path){

 ofstream myfile;
 myfile.open(file_path);

    myfile << (*this);
    cout << "Game has been saved!" << endl;
    myfile.close();
}
```

**Definition of ostream [FOR PRINTING THE BOARD ON TERMINAL]**

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream& outputStream, Hex& obj){
    if(obj.getGameplayType() == 1){
        outputStream << "Player1's Score: " << obj.getScoreP1() << " points" << "  |  Player2's Score: " << obj.getScoreP2() << " points";
    }
    else{
        outputStream << "Player's Score: " << obj.getScoreP1() << " points";
    }

    outputStream << "\n\n ";
    for(int i=0; i<obj.getBoardSize(); i++){
        outputStream << " " <<obj.hexCells[0][i].column;
    }
    outputStream << endl;
    for(int i=0; i<obj.getBoardSize(); i++){
        outputStream << i + 1;
        if(i+1 < 10) outputStream << " "; 
        if(i >= 1){
            for(int j=0; j<i; j++) outputStream << " ";
        }
        for(int k=0; k<obj.getBoardSize(); k++){
            outputStream << " " << obj.hexCells[i][k].point;
        }
        outputStream << endl;
    }
return outputStream;
}
```

**Definition of ofstream [FOR SAVING THE ACTIVE GAME INTO A .TXT FILE]**

```
ofstream& operator <<(ofstream& fileOutput, const Hex& obj){
    fileOutput << obj.getGameplayType() << endl;
    fileOutput << obj.getBoardSize() << endl;
    fileOutput << obj.getTurn() << endl;

    for(int i=0; i<obj.getBoardSize(); i++){
        for(int k=0; k<obj.getBoardSize(); k++){
            fileOutput << obj.hexCells[i][k].point;  
        }
        fileOutput << endl;
    }
return fileOutput;
}
```

I searched my answer on net and I get some help but I did not fix this error yet. I fixed other ambiguity problem by adding explicit keyword before Hex constructors but this one is not fixed. Can someone help me?

(I must overload << for both ostream and ofstream. This is my homework and my classmates did it like this way but they did not get any warning. If there's another way (correct) I want to learn and implement into my code.)

Comment: Why do you think you need both overloads? An output file stream (`std::ofstream`) is *also* an output stream (`std::ostream`). If you want special handling for e.g. a save-file (as opposed to general output to any file, including standard output) then I recommend you write a special function for that instead of overloading `operator<<`.

Comment: `I must overload << for both ostream and ofstream ... my teacher wants it like that` Either your teacher is not very good at C++, or you misunderstood them. The right person to ask this question to is your teacher. No-one here is going to show you how to write bad code.

Comment: The error is talking about a `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Hex&)` (without const) which you appear to have on line 207 and are not showing us?

Comment: The important detail: [`std::ofstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream) inherits from `std::ostream`.

Comment: Are you sure that you're not supposed to have a Game class and a Board class? Having `operator<<(std::ofstream&, const Game&)` and `operator<<(std::ostream&, const Board&)` would make some sense.

Comment: @john "Overload stream insertion and extraction operators. Use these operators for both screen prints and file input output." This is my teacher's sentence. My classmates did it like that so I though I must do like them. They don't get a warning.

Comment: @dratenik That function is correct. "const" is not supoosed to be there. My fault. I did some changes to fix the warning. I removed const now.

Comment: @molbdnilo No , I don't supposed to have these classes. I can only use Hex class.

Comment: "Use these operators for both screen prints and file ... output." I read that as the overload should be able to take any output stream (be it an `std::ofstream` object, or `std::cout`). In other words, a single`std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Hex const&)` function. Then you also need an "input" function as well, `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Hex&)`, that can read and parse the contents created by your `operator<<` function.

Comment: So why does it need a conversion for #2 in the first place? Is your saveGame declared with a `const` modifier by any chance?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Walter Savitch's Absolute C++ book says that I can use ostream for both cout and file output but I did not find any example to show me how to implement one overload function for 2 special operation. The example on the book says that I can use default parameter to check that but I can not use any default parameter with operator overloading (I tried that but get an error). How can I separate a function (operator overloading) for both cout and file output?

Comment: @dratenik Here's the declaration of saveGame in hex_game.h: `void saveGame(const string& file_path);` .

Comment: @ardakilic Your teacher didn't say overload stream insertion operators for **both** `ostream` and `ofstream`. That is where your mistake is. In other words you misunderstood your teacher (and your teacher seems to be OK at C++). Just overload for `ostream` which will then also work for `ofstream`.

Comment: @ardakilic If you need different output operations for `cout` and files, then don't overload `<<` for both. I would recommend a special function for `cout` and to use `<<` for files.

Comment: Your teacher did not say to overload the operators for both screen and file I/O, but that you should *use* your overloads for both screen and file I/O. (This is more a hint that there should only be one `<<` than a requirement for two of them.)

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case, that means changing ’ofstream myfile; myfile.open(file_path);` to `ofstream myfile(file_path);`. And you don’t need to call `myfile.close();`. The destructor will do that.